# Pagination in android Recycler View fetching items from urls

Tags: android, url, pagination, android-recyclerview, httpclient

I am working on an android app where I am fetching data for my recycler view from a URL in chuncks of 10 items at a time using the following URLs. I am not able to understand how to change adapter data set on scroll?

Pagination: You can load next page of results by changing the start parameter in the API.
For Example:
Page 1: http://api.smartprix.com/simple/v1?type=search&key=NVgien7bb7P5Gsc8DWqc&category=Mobiles&q=3g&start=0&indent=1
Page 2: http://api.smartprix.com/simple/v1?type=search&key=NVgien7bb7P5Gsc8DWqc&category=Mobiles&q=3g&start=10&indent=1

This is the code I am using to get items from the urls:-

```
  private class FetchProductsTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response;
        String responseString = null;
        try {
            // make a HTTP request
            response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(params[0]));
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            if (statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                Log.d(TAG,"HTTP request status is OK");
                ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
                out.close();
                responseString = out.toString();
            } else {
                // close connection
                Log.d(TAG,"HTTP request status is close connection");
                response.getEntity().getContent().close();
                throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Couldn't make a successful request!"+e);
        }
        return responseString;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
        super.onPostExecute(response);

        try {
            // convert the String response to a JSON object
            Log.d(TAG,"Response = "+response);
            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);

            // fetch the array of movies in the response
            JSONArray jArray = jsonResponse.getJSONObject("request_result").getJSONArray("results");
            Log.d(TAG,"jArray = "+jArray.toString());


            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {

                Log.d(TAG,"product = "+jArray.get(i));
                JSONObject product = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                products.add(new ProductDataForList(product.getString("id"),product.getString("name"),product.getString("img_url"),product.getInt("price")));
                /*movieTitles.add(movie.getString("title"));


                movieSynopsis.add(movie.getString(movie.getString("synopsis")));
                movieImgUrl.add(movie.getString(movie.getString("id")));*/
            }
            // refresh the ListView
            fillProductList(products);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.d("Test", "Couldn't successfully parse the JSON response!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check [this](https://github.com/MarkoMilos/Paginate)

Answer (score 0):

take a int start=0;

```
recyclerview.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            int lastItem = mLayoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
            if (lastItem == ArrayList.size() - 1) {
            start=start+10;
            //now hit you api
            hitapi(start);

        }
    });
    hitapi(int start){
         //in your api set this start parameter value
         //weher you recive the response add your new list to the bottom of new list and call adapter.notifydatasetchanged
        responseArrayList.clear();
        responseArrayList.addAll(flaersPOJO.flares);
        ArrayList<Flare> newList = new ArrayList<Flare>(OrignalArrayList);
        newList.addAll(responseArrayList);
        OrignalArrayList.clear();
        OrignalArrayList.addAll(newList);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
      //try somtinhg like this 
     }
```

ask me if any difficulties or do let me know if it worked